# Is there a way to rotate the hover highlight on a link? (not element)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Apologies if this is a noobish question, but I wanted to see if it was possible to rotate the highlight on a link when hovered?

So, I have my css/html set up like this:

```css
.links {
  display: block;
}

.links a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #000;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.links a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 50px 0 0 #ea1a00;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="example.com">
    <span>Link example</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

*(Edited from teaclub.crd.co)*
My goal was to have it so when the link is hovered on, the red highlight (not the text) will rotate a certain amount?

I've tried the transform: rotate function but it's always applied to the text, and I'm unsure if there is a way to seperate them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried a reverse rotation for the text or rotate a pseudo element instead the link itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.links {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.links a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #000;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.links a:hover .rotate {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.rotate {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 6px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="example.com"><span style="font-family: 'Arsenal', sans-serif;">Link example</span>
        <span class="rotate"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's perfect!! I just edited the position to align with the text. Thank you so much for your help!! Definitely noted for future reference.